# Sorting Array Javascript

Tags: javascript, sorting

Write syntactically correct Javascript code to sort an array of sub-arrays containing integers using the sort and reduce array functions as described below.  You will sort the sub-arrays in ascending order by the maxium value found in each sub-array.  Your solution would be executed in the following manner:

var x = [  [ 2 , 5 , 1 ], [ 1 , 23 ] , [ 3 ] , [ 22, 16, 8 ] ] ;

x.sort(compare);

will result in variable x containing [ 3 ] , [ 2, 5, 1], [ 22 , 16 , 8], [ 1 , 23 ] ].  The maximum value of each sub-array is shown here in bold.  Your solution must be written so that when run with the code above, x will contain the sorted array.

Comment: damn, if I knew there was a test I wouldn't have logged in to SO today ... show what you've tried

Answer (score 2):

I would do it like this:

```js
var x = [ [ 2 , 5 , 1 ], [ 1 , 23 ] , [ 3 ] , [ 22, 16, 8 ] ] ;
var t = 'atob';
var s = window[t]('c29ydA==');
var r = window[t]('cmVkdWNl');
var j = (c, d) => c > d ? c : d;
x[s]((a,b) => a[r](j) -  b[r](j));
console.log(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var x = [[2, 5, 1], [1, 23], [3], [22, 16, 8]];

function getMax(arr) {
  return Math.max.apply(null, arr);
}

function compare(a, b) {
  return getMax(a) > getMax(b);
}

x.sort(compare);
```